# Is there a way to chroot/sandbox a go os.exec call (prevent rm -rf /)

Tags: macos, go, chroot

I want to test/automate some repositories, the basic flow is something like:

```
repos := []string{"repo 1", "repo 2", ...}
for r := range repos {
    // git clone the repo 
    // cd repo dir
    // make test
    // make build
    // ...
}
```

I am doing this with [GO](https://golang.org/) using  `os.exec` to call the all the series of commands, something like:

```
 exec.Command("sh", "-c", "git clone project")
```

So far so good, but I would like to know if there is a way to secure/protect against something miswriting on the Makefile that could be doing something like `rm -rf /`. and break my host.

Basically I would like to use the system libraries/tools but restrict/chroot only the output to a specific `workdir`, so that I can avoid pre-build a chroot for this.

A working solution is to use a [FreeBSD jail](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/jails.html), but I would like to know if there an alternative/secure way of doing this without the need of containers,virtualbox,etc; and using a basic Mac OS X workstation. so that anyone could "safely" run & test without worries.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What kind of sandboxing do you need? You need to sandbox just the file system or other things like network sockets?

Comment: There's a package called syscall, it has a Chroot function that might do what you need: https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/

Comment: I need sandbox only for the file system

Comment: @robbrit I think I am not properly using the syscall/chroot any chance you could share an example?

Comment: Unfortunately I've never used it, I just Googled for something that might do what you want. You'd have to test it out for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine using os.Setuid/os.Setgid (example.go):

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "flag"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    var oUid = flag.Int("uid", 0, "Run with User ID")
    var oGid = flag.Int("gid", 0, "Run with Group ID")
    flag.Parse()

    // Get UID/GUID from args
    var uid = *oUid
    var gid = *oGid

    // Run whoami
    out, err := exec.Command("whoami").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    // Output whoami
    log.Println("Original UID/GID whoami:", string(out))
    log.Println("Setting UID/GUID")

    // Change privileges
    err = syscall.Setgid(gid)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Cannot setgid")
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    err = syscall.Setuid(uid)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Cannot setuid")
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    // Execute whoami again
    out, err = exec.Command("whoami").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }
    log.Println("Changed UID/GID whoami:", string(out))


    // Do some dangerous stuff
    log.Println("Creating a executable file within /bin should fail...")
    _, err = os.Create("/bin/should-fail")
    if err == nil {
        log.Println("Warning: operation did not fail")
        return
    }

    log.Println("We are fine", err)
}
```

I would also recommend to read about setting gid/uid properly (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166817/using-the-setuid-bit-properly, in C). Oh! its needed to set gid before uid, because the example fails if you don't do so.

You should execute `example.go` with root privileges and specify unprivileged gid/uid to the command with flags -gid,-uid respectively.

```
sudo go run example.go -uid <unprivileged id> -gid <unprivileged id>
```